# Phonegap jQuery mobile event handling performance?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I've build an Android app in Phonegap and jQuery Mobile and now I want to optimize it, so it will run smoother. I have few performance questions:

1. What is best use of click event handling (for perforamance)

   ```
   $('#someID').on('click', function());
   $('#someID').click(function());
   $('#someID').on('vclick', function());
   ```
2. Is there binded pageshow event, so I wouldn't have to do it with live?

   ```
   $('#somePageId').pageshow(function())
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $('#somePageId').on('pageshow', function())
   ```
3. Any other tips for better performance will be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your problem aside, isn't .live deprecated?

Comment: Yes sry I will edit the question.

Comment: not really 100% sure but isn't `$('#someID').click(callback);` just a shorthand for `$('#someID').on('click', callback);` if you want a live like behaviour you need the delegated approach `$(parent_container_selector).on('pageshow', page_selector, callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delegation -> $(document).on('click','#someID', function(e){...});
2. Use delegate

Comment: Is the suggestion #1 noticable faster than .live ?

Comment: If you have high number of items delegate is lighter, if you want speed attach handler directly to element

Comment: do you mean <a href="" onClick="event()"> ??? is this noticable faster on mobiles if you have around 30 events?

Comment: If you have 30 different dom object with different events is fast $("#id").on("click",calback);.
If you have 30 dom object that must use the same handler use delgation

Comment: I have 12 DOM objects and 2 or 3 event handlers on each DOM. Will it make the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily related to Phonegap/JQM, but this [list](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is helpful.

If you look on the JQM forum, there is a lengthy [post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/reaction-from-jquery-mobile-community-on-phonegap-post) with a lot of info on how others optimize their PhoneGap/JQM applications.

That should get you started in the right direction.